# Как google-gson парсером извлечь данные?

Tags: gson, json, java

есть строка

```
 String str = 
    [{"name": "Victor"}, 
    {"name": "Alex"}, 
    {"name": "Smit"}, 
    {"name": "Anastasy"}]
```

нужно извлечь из нее имена парсером json
делаю так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Pars p = gson.fromJson(str, Pars.class);
String s = p.getName();
```

класс Pars:

```
public class Pars {

    public static String name;

    public String getName() {
    return  name;

}

}
```

код не работает, ошибка JsonSyntaxException
помогите!

Comment: если уж GSON, то язык, стало быть - Gava)))

Comment: GSon это гуглевский парсер JSon :) Так что вопрос корректный

Comment: правда? тогда мои извинения автору вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Замените

```
Pars p = gson.fromJson(str, Pars.class);
```

на

```
Pars[] p = gson.fromJson(str, Pars[].class);
```

И уберите `static` у поля `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Измененный ответ.

проверил на http://json.parser.online.fr/, ваша json-строка правильная.
Дело в том что у вас в строке находится МАССИВ объектов, а парсером вы пытаетесь распарсить строку в одиночный ОБЪЕКТ.
Ошибка в строке:

```
Pars p = gson.fromJson(str, Pars.class);
```

ДОлжно быть что то типа:

```
Pars[] pArray = gson.fromJson(str, Pars.class);
```

Comment: мне сервер дает ответ именно в таком виде, в котором я показал.
т.е нужно переделать не строку, а код.
спасибо! p.s меня уже тошнит от этих парсеров :) вчера весь день пытался распарсить строку через json-simple, под утро сделал вывод, что под андроид работать с ним невозможно. :)

Comment: Тогда у вас два варианта:
1) сложный - написать свой парсер этого неполного JSON
2) простой - довести входную строку до корректного формата и далее парсить.

Comment: а возможно ли использовать другой парсер, в котором есть поддержка такого вида строки? допустим вот здесь http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes в самом конце страницы как раз мой пример.

Comment: стоп. я ошибся, json может содержать массив объектов, тогда он заключается в квадратные скобки. щас поправлю свой ответ.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался. :)